# In MySQL 5.7 how would I select all parent table rows with less than 2 related child table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Again this is a MySQL 5.7 DB.  For example, let's say I have a database for a car lot, a table for cars and a table for price updates.  (This is a contrived example).

```
Database: CarLot
Table: Cars
-Id
-Year
-Make
-Model

Table: PriceUpdates
-Id
-CarId (FK Cars:Id)
-Price
-DateChanged
```

To pseudo code what I want to do would look like:

SELECT * from Cars WHERE a Car has < 2 PriceUpdate rows (for each given CarId there are less than 2 associated PriceUpdate rows)

I'm not super strong in SQL and not sure if it's doable in a simple query or if I have to get into a procedure or T-SQL or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A join query with an assertion on the count should work here:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Cars c
LEFT JOIN PriceUpdates pu
    ON c.Id = pu.CarId
GROUP BY
    c.Id
HAVING
    COUNT(pu.CarId) < 2;
```

Note: In MySQL (and ANSI SQL) it is completely valid to group by `Cars.Id` and select all other columns from this table because these columns are functionally dependent on the `Id` column.

Comment: This is great!  Works like a charm.  Thanks for the quick response!  I knew it had to have something to do with HAVING :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the prices as well (which seems likely despite your pseudo-code), then `exists` would often be used:

```
SELECT c.*, pu.*
FROM Cars c LEFT JOIN
     PriceUpdates pu
     ON c.Id = pu.CarId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM PriceUpdates pu2
                  WHERE pu2.CarId = pu.CarId AND
                        pu2.Id <> pu.Id
                 );
```